# Module over a commutative local ring has nonzero homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, group-homomorphism, local-rings

The question is from a Persian text book:

Let $R$ be a commutative local ring with $1$, and $\mathfrak m$ its maximal ideal. If $M$ is a non-zero module over $R$ prove that $\text{Hom}_R(M,R/\mathfrak m) \neq 0$.

I have managed to prove this when $M$ is finitely generated by Nakayama lemma, we use it to show that $M/\mathfrak mM \neq 0$, but I couldn't progress for the case when $M$ is not finitely generated, I just proved that the problem is equivalent to the statement below:
$$M \neq \mathfrak mM.$$
Any help or hint is appreciated.

---

**Edit**:

Seems like for the case that $M$ is not finitely generated we have the following counter example:

$$R= \mathbb{R}[[x]], M= \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} a_i x^i$$

Comment: What you wrote $M = \sum_{i \in \Bbb{Z}} a_i x^i$ is a power series (usually an element of a space) so certainly not a whole module space.

Comment: A classical example when NAK fails is $R=\mathbb Z_{(p)}$ and $M=\mathbb Q$. ($p$ prime) In this case your Hom is zero.